# Python JSON dictionary key error

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to collect data from a JSON file using python. I was able to access several chunks of text but when I get to the 3rd object in the JSON file I'm getting a key error. The first three lines work fine but the last line gives me a key error.

```
response = urllib.urlopen("http://asn.desire2learn.com/resources/D2740436.json")
data = json.loads(response.read())

title = data["http://asn.desire2learn.com/resources/D2740436"]["http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title"][0]["value"]

description = data["http://asn.desire2learn.com/resources/D2740436"]["http://purl.org/dc/terms/description"][0]["value"]

topics = data["http://asn.desire2learn.com/resources/D2740436"]["http://purl.org/gem/qualifiers/hasChild"]

topicDesc = data["http://asn.desire2learn.com/resources/S2743916"]
```

Here is the JSON file I'm using. http://s3.amazonaws.com/asnstaticd2l/data/rdf/D2742493.json I went through all the braces and can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Anyone know why I might be getting this?

Comment: Um... The file that you linked to isn't the file you referenced in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
topics = data["http://asn.desire2learn.com/resources/D2740436"]["http://purl.org/gem/qualifiers/hasChild"]
```

I don't see this key "http://asn.desire2learn.com/resources/D2740436" anywhere in your source file. You didn't include your stack, but my first thought would be typo resulting in a bad key and you getting an error like:

```
KeyError: "http://asn.desire2learn.com/resources/D2740436"
```

Which means that value does not exist in the data you are referencing

Answer (score 0):

The link in your code and your AWS link go to very different files. Open up [the link in your code](http://asn.desire2learn.com/resources/D2740436.json) in a web browser, and you will find that it's much shorter than the file on AWS. It doesn't actually contain the key you're looking for.

Comment: Oh my god this was so nooby. The website I was getting these files from was a total mess and there were 3 different files for everything. I fixed the problem, thanks so much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are using the linked file, in which the key `"http://asn.desire2learn.com/resources/S2743916"` turns up once.

However, your code is downloading a different file - one in which the key does not appear.

Try using the file you linked in your code, and you should see the key will work.